# How much computing is required to "unfold" corona? Why is it so slow?

Tags: folding-at-home

I have seen several challenges to join different Folding@Home teams to unfold the corona virus and am a little surprised about the whole situation. I participated in Folding@Home during the 90s and they made good progress back then in different projects.

More than 20 years later the computers are thousands, if not millions (esp. GPUs), times faster and considering the engagement corona has generated my spontaneous feeling is that it should have been unfolded in a day or something like that (almost in a matter of minutes as soon as the Folding-network became efficient) but that does not seem to be the case.

**Can someone explain the situation? How many flop (or whatever) does it take to "unfold" a virus like corona? How does the capacity of the Folding-network compare to that number? Why isn't this already done (considering the capacity of today's computers and the Folding-network)?**

(And feel free to add other relevant details that I might not have been aware that I should have asked about)

Comment: there is no one operation of "unfolding"

Comment: we must simulate thousands of (random) protein pathways

Comment: I have voted to close this question due to it being out of scope here at Super User.